# Brownie installation

Tags: brownie

```
hp@DESKTOP-QUTE621 MINGW64 \~/demos/nft-demo
$ brownie run scripts/deploy_and_create.py --network rinkeby
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

NftDemoProject is the active project.
File "c:\\python\\python3810\\lib\\site-packages\\brownie_cli\__main_\_.py", line 64, in main
importlib.import_module(f"brownie.\_cli.{cmd}").main()
File "c:\\python\\python3810\\lib\\site-packages\\brownie_cli\\run.py", line 45, in main
network.connect(CONFIG.argv\["network"\])
File "c:\\python\\python3810\\lib\\site-packages\\brownie\\network\\main.py", line 40, in connect
web3.connect(host, active.get("timeout", 30))
File "c:\\python\\python3810\\lib\\site-packages\\brownie\\network\\web3.py", line 52, in connect
uri = \_expand_environment_vars(uri)
File "c:\\python\\python3810\\lib\\site-packages\\brownie\\network\\web3.py", line 183, in \_expand_environment_vars
raise ValueError(f"Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: '{uri}'")
ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'
```

how can i correct this error  so that my program will and connect to network?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID` in `.env` file to connect to network.